# Activity Access Control - Restrict to contact group

Tags: activities, acl

Using Civi 5.38 on a WordPress site

We use 3 levels of user role which I manage through the WordPress Access Control screen. I want to retrict some of the acitivities within the roles and am using the Activity Type ACL which gives me the options to add, view, edit etc as required however...I don't seem to be able to grant edit access on activities without the "CiviCRM: edit all contacts" permission being ticked. I only want these roles to edit one of the contact groups and have an ACL setup to allow this, but I can't seem to allow edit activities just for that group without having to allow edit on all contacts in the database, is there any way around this? thanks